# Calculating Based on an Array in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a Pivot Table that I am able to cycle through the different months based on a Month Filter (changing the data of the table). I am trying to calculate based off of that change of value. I am recording the amount of times a license is used in a workday. The number of workdays in a month change based on the month. I calculated out the workdays for each month using

```
=NETWORKDAYS(H34,EOMONTH(H34,0),J34:J45)
```

`H34` references my `1/1/2016` date. `J34:J45` references my holiday dates to avoid.

I am trying to write a formula that says "If the month listed (from my month filter) within the Months list then to print the corresponding Workdays value.

```
=IF(G34:G46=H48, I34:I46)
```

It only works on January. The rest of the values return False. I do calculate it as an Array Function. It returns either False. I cannot think of another function that could replace it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
2016            
   Month    Date    Workdays    Holiday Dates   Holidays
  January   1/1/2016    19       1/1/2016   New Year's day
  February  2/1/2016    20       18-Jan     Holiday 2
  March     3/1/2016    22      2/15/2016   Valentines day
  April     4/1/2016    21     3/25/2016    St. Patrick's Day
   May      5/1/2016    21     5/30/2016    Memorial Day
  June      6/1/2016    22      7/4/2016    Independence Day
  July      7/1/2016    21      9/5/2016    Labor Day
  August    8/1/2016    23      10/10/2016  Holiday
September   9/1/2016    22      11/8/2016   Columbus Day
 October    10/1/2016   21      11/11/2016  Veteran's Day
 November   11/1/2016   21      11/24/2016  Thanksgiving
 December   12/1/2016   21      12/26/2016  Christmas
  All              235      

  Selected Month            
    March   FALSE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [VLOOKUP()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1) function will greatly simplify this process for you.  This particular function is great for extracting values in a list based on a key lookup field.

In your example, you want to easily extract the value from *Holiday Dates* column based on an input month.

[image]

A few things to keep in mind for the input parameter functions in this function:

- The first column in your table array must contain the lookup value, in this case, the month column.
- If may need to lock your array dimensions, use the **$** sign in front of the column letter and row number.
- FALSE should be selected for the *range_lookup* in order to do exact matching for the lookup value.  If you choose false, you may get false positivies.
- Every row in your list should be unique for the lookup value.  Let's say January was listed twice, the value returned would be for the first occurrence.

Additional info:

- http://spreadsheeto.com/vlookup/
- http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13780/using-vlookup-in-excel/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LOOKUP function, as follow:

`=VLOOKUP(G48,G34:I45,3)`

This formula looks up "G48" value in column G (first matrix column), and returns the value from column I (third matrix column) that is in the same row.

Read this official Office [page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOOKUP-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb) for more details.

Please, give us your feedback.